# Global settings accessible by all apps - Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Within windows phone development, are there any values/variables stored which are fundamental to the phone itself and can be accessed from any app? For example power count, generic app info etc. If so where could I find a list of these accessible variables/data?

Comment: have you many other sample of "values fundamentales to the phone itself" ? You want retreive what informations precisely? wifi available? phone number?  application version? application name?

Comment: I would want to know how many times each specific app has been launched - if possible.

Comment: your application? Or all application on the device?

Comment: All apps on the device. I'm curious to know what data windows phone exposes about 'everything' apart from a single app.

Comment: There is no central data store on the phone that is accessible by all apps. App cannot (and should not) be able to access each other's info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ther are any phone-wide variables you can use. As it would be difficult to maintain continuity throughout the apps that use it, as any could change its value.

You would have to create a server to interchange information between applications that you have made. I believe this is the only way.

And of course you can't access isolatedStorage as it is "Isolated" and only accessible by that application.

As for app-wide variables you can use this:

You can set variables in App.xaml like so:

```
Public int powerCount { get; set; }
```

And access them from other pages using:

```
(App.Current as App).powerCount = 3;
```

Or of course you could use IsolatedStorage.